# The last command line in the shell script without a newline

Tags: shell-script

Why can the last command line in the shell script (`uptime` below) be executed successfully without the newline at the end of the file?

For example:

```
root@jcdb:/tmp# 
root@jcdb:/tmp# 
root@jcdb:/tmp# cat dp
date
pwd
uptimeroot@jcdb:/tmp# 
root@jcdb:/tmp# 
root@jcdb:/tmp# 
root@jcdb:/tmp# ./dp
Wed Jun  6 16:27:26 EAT 2018
/tmp
  4:27pm  up 1 day, 17:25,  2 users,  load average: 0.39, 0.40, 0.41
root@jcdb:/tmp# 
root@jcdb:/tmp#
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When the shell reads the shell script, its scanning code will accept the last word at the end of the script even if there is no terminating newline.

This is the effect of [the first rule in the POSIX standard regarding how the shell should recognize tokens in its input](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_03):

> If the end of input is recognized, the current token (if any) shall be delimited.

The fact that it say that the current token is delimited here means that the last word in the script, along with the rest of that non-terminated line, will be accepted as input to the interpreter rather than causing an error or putting the shell into an undefined state.

---

In comments, a reference is made to the `vi` editor.  A standard `vi` editor is allowed to edit a file whose last line is not terminated by a newline. It will, however, terminate the last line of the buffer with a newline when writing it to file (except for when saving an empty file, in which case adding a newline is explicitly not allowed).  This is also true for a standard `ex` editor:

> INPUT FILES
>
> Input files shall be text files or files that would be text files except for an incomplete last line that is not longer than `{LINE_MAX}-1` bytes in length and contains no `NUL` characters. By default, any incomplete last line shall be treated as if it had a trailing `<newline>`. The editing of other forms of files may optionally be allowed by `ex` implementations.

The `vim` editor has a setting, `eol`, which determines whether it should preserve the non-terminated last line or not.  The default behaviour is to terminate the last line.  See `:help eol` in `vim`.

The input to the standard `ed` editor is supposed to be a text file, which means that what happens if one is editing a file whose last line in not properly terminated (which makes it not a text file) is technically unspecified.  On OpenBSD, the `ed` editor will say "newline appended" when opening a non-terminated text file.

> INPUT FILES
>
> The input files shall be text files.

Comment: Thanks！

1) Do all the types of shell, such as ksh/sh/csh/bash, conform to the POSIX  standard rule ？
2) But indeed the last command line is still regarded as a incomplete line while the script is opened with vi ！

Comment: @lylklb All of those shells, with the exception of `csh`, are POSIX shells and should behave the same way with regards to this. `csh` is not a POSIX shell, so you would have to test that individually.  I don't think I understand your second question. Normally a "line" needs to be terminated by a newline, but since the POSIX parsing rules for shell scripts have this special rule, the last line of a shell script may remain unterminated.

Comment: 1) I have tested it in the csh environment, and it also work fine w/o last newline！
2) It is just a message at the bottom of vi editor that prompts "Incomplete last line". 
I think that this symptom is mainly due to the  non-POSIX compliant systems/editors！

Comment: @lylklb 1) Good. 2) No it is not.  The lines of a text file should all be delimited by a newline character.  The parsing rules for shell script allows the last line to be unterminated.  This allows the shell to execute scripts which are read from a command substitution, like `sh -c "$(cat script)"`.  The last line of `script` will not be terminated by a newline when given to the `sh` interpreter, since the command substitution removes it.  Also, in `printf 'echo hello' | sh` the script (`echo hello`) does not have a newline at the end.

Comment: Could you please tell me where can be found with more detail/documents about this parsing rule for the last line in shell scripts ？

Comment: @lylklb What more information would you require? The standard says that an unterminated final line will be accepted by the interpreter since the last word (if any) before the end of input will be delimited (i.e. will not be an error or otherwise put the shell into an undefined state).

Comment: Your example statements are so wonderful！ I have tested them all, and find that the delimitation of last line is indeed confirmed by the shell interpreter！

Notes: you are right that the csh strictly should not be a POSIX shell, but except for HP-UX's csh though I don't know why about it！

Comment: @lylklb The `csh` (and `tcsh`) shell simply has a syntax that is so unlike the `sh` shells' syntax that it's not a POSIX shell. The `csh` shell is really quite different to work with when it comes to shell scripting, and the `sh` shells are incompatible with it.